# Где в спецификациях W3C отражена возможность использования document.body?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Как известно, чтобы получить элемент `body` HTML-документа на языке JS можно написать просто

```
var body = document.body;
```

Однако, просматривая спецификацию `W3C DOM level 3`, я не нашел, где говорится о такой возможности. Поэтому хотелось бы получить ссылку на нормативный документ, в котором описывается допустимость такой конструкции.

Comment: На более позднюю спеку ссылка устроит? (Вообще это в немного другой спеке описано насколько я понимаю, вот)  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-body

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Да мне важно лишь, чтобы это было отражено в каком-нибудь нормативном документе.

Comment: Ну собственно я ссылку кинул, это в html спеке а не в dom

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму То же самое имеет место на W3C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это написано в  HTML спецификации, а не в DOM, для текущей спеки в разделе 3.1.3 DOM Tree accessors.

Например тут (живой стандарт): 
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-body

Или тут (спека от 28.10.2014): https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-tree-accessors